# Java process order causes performance issues

Tags: java, linux, performance, solr, profiling

I have a search application that uses a native search (I wrote) and solr text search. This is a heavy multi-threaded application which runs on several nodes. The problem is, when my solr processes come up first during application initialization, my other search processes (native ones) perform poor about 40% lower, but when my native search processes come up first and followed by solr processes, it performs great.

I did some memory, heap, gc and THP analysis. But couldn't really explain why. I know that the order of initialization causes this issue but don't know what is causing it. I do have enough available memory for all these processes. I do noticed that with the solr first initialization, my searches on my native search process performs 30% slower and uses 30% less cpu across all the nodes. So I'm kind of ran out of idea on where to look for other clues. any suggestion ?